# How do I donate troops to my clan members?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do I donate troops to the clan castle? Can I only donate troops when they are requested on a clan chat?

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: @TimS. That's why it has 4 up votes?

Comment: When I posted that comment, it was -1, and I brought it up to 0, with no other votes. Glad to see it was upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

In order to receive troops a player needs to request it in his clan castle. Requests are displayed in clan chat and teammates can give 5 units (or more if unlocked by clan exp). If more space is still available, the same teammate can only provide additional troop if request is made again, knowing that there is a minimum delay between each request (time varying with clan exp).

During a clan war, a request is not required from the member for defensive troops.  These troops remain in the castle throughout the war and defend it. Offensive troops have to be requested in the normal manner.  When viewing your home war map, defensive troops can be donated to any clan member whose castle is not already full.  Be sure to see what defensive troops that member has specified beforehand before you donate.

Comment: You can also donate to war clan castles

Comment: True, I didn't think about war castle. Note it is possible only if you are engaged in the war. Spectators can't donate @Ben Craig.